# How to properly use time zone in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The logic: I want to show placeholder exercises if no log entries for today exists. If log entries for today exists, then don't show placeholder exercises even if they exist.

```
      .log-entries
        - unless exercise.log_entries.for_user(workout.user).blank? || exercise.last_log_date(workout.user) == Time.zone.today.beginning_of_day
          %p Nice job performing this #{timeago exercise.last_log_date(workout.user)}. Try going up in difficulty this time.
          = exercise.last_log_date(workout.user).to_date
          = exercise.last_log_entry(workout.user).created_at.to_date
          %br
          = Time.current.to_date
          %br
          - for log_entry in exercise.placeholder_log_entries!(workout.user)
            = render 'log_entries/form', log_entry: log_entry, exercise: exercise
        - for log_entry in exercise.log_entries.for_today.order("created_at ASC").for_user(workout.user) do
          = render 'log_entries/form', log_entry: log_entry, exercise: exercise
        - if exercise.log_entries.blank?
          %p.hint.not-performed-yet You haven't performed this exercise yet.

      = link_to exercise.render_add_text, user_workout_exercise_log_entries_path(workout, workout.user, exercise), class: "button radius", remote: true, method: :post
```

Whats driving me nuts... is that I recorded log entries for today, yet placeholder exercises are still showing up. So that first `unless` is passing.

Upon debugging I'll get values like this:

```
exercise last log date: 2013-08-26 00:00:00 -0700 
today: 2013-08-27 00:00:00 -0700
```

But that exer last log date is actually recorded today, just right now! Why is it a day behind?

```
 #<LogEntry id: 226, reps: 8, weight: 55, effort: nil, description: nil, loggable_id: 3, loggable_type: "Exercise", created_at: "2013-08-27 06:00:12", updated_at: "2013-08-28 03:06:56", user_id: 1, rest_after_set: nil, difficulty: nil, distance: nil, duration: nil, measurement: nil, placeholder: false>
```

Created at is 2013-08-27!!! Why is it rendering 26 in the view? I'm losing my mind.

Comment: Can you post the code for the exercise.last_log_date(workout.user) method?

Answer (score 0):

Time zone management in Ruby on Rails usually requires you to set `config.time_zone` which "sets the default time zone for the application and enables time zone awareness for Active Record" and using the localize helper `I18n.l` or just `l`.

Examples:

```
I18n.l(Time.now)

l(Time.now)
```

Have a look at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#configure-the-i18n-module.